# Any way to disable "use password" button in expo LocalAuthentication?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, authentication, expo, fingerprint

Here is my code

```
        const result = await LocalAuthentication.authenticateAsync({
            promptMessage: 'Screen lock security',
        });
```

I am using LocalAuthentication.authenticateAsync to get access to fingerprint or face detection but I dont want to let user to use other method like password or pattern. How can I disable the button?

Thanks!

Comment: just to keep in mind, if the faceId is corrupted or the fingerprint scanner is faulty

Comment: @FaysalB I want to use the app login password instead of device password to verify if biometric is not success.